# Wrong contentSize in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've created my custom layout for a UICollectionView. I've subclassed the `prepare()` and `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()` methods.

The problem is that the `contentSize`'s width doesn't correspond to the sum of my two cells width. The scroll direction is `horizontal`.

Comment: Did you override the contentSize in your custom layout?

Comment: No, i don't override the contentSize in my custom layout

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize?language=objc "Subclasses must override this method and use it to return the width and height of the collection view’s content."... "The default implementation of this method returns CGSizeZero."

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout prepareLayout];
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutIfNeeded];
```